# PHP post request returns 400 error

Tags: php, post, request

I have the following class, it's using a web service to send a request and get a JSON response back.
When i try the same thing with Chrome's Postman extension, I get a nice little response back.

```
class RequestController {

    function  __construct() {

        global $config;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    function send_request() {

        $url = $this->config['GATEWAY']['url'] . 'getbyquery';

        $json_data = '{"query":{"AllFields":true,"ConditionSetOperator":0,"ConditionSets":[],"Distinct":false,"Fields":["jay_alb","jay_levelms"],"Links":[],"Orders":[],"RecordType":"jay_lifeinsurance","Top":0}}';
        $data = array($json_data);

        $options = array(
                        'http' => array(
                        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'content' => http_build_query($data),
                        ),
                    );

        $context  = stream_context_create($options);

        print "<pre>";
        print_r($options);
        print "</pre>";

        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $data = json_decode($result);
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

However when I'm using my class I get an error.

Warning: file_get_contents(http://crm-gateway.premier.com.au/GatewayService.svc/getbyquery) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\crm\includes\classes\RequestController.php on line 32

Can you please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use cURL for better handling these kind of issues

Comment: If you actually try following the link, you will see you get a 404 error, so this is not a problem with your code

Comment: It's a internal link, not accessible via the intenet